# Is org.testng.asserts.softAssert class a singleton class?

Tags: testng, assertion

Is **org.testng.asserts.softAssert** class a singleton class?

We are trying to run multiple test cases by placing the assertions code in common functions where the assertion is a static variable and at the end of each test case, we are trying assertAll method to validate all soft assertions. Due to this if a single test case got failed all the following test cases are failing by throwing the earlier assertions.